alert = driver.switch_to.alert
I am getting No Alert and I am not sure why. I would want alert accepted to finish the process on updating the asset that is being scanned
def scan_thread(usr_obj, code, scan_mode, success_func, fail_func, *args):
    global driver
    print("scan_thread")

    if not driver:
        init_driver(usr_obj)

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    if code.strip():
        os.system("cls")
        print(code.strip(), "was scanned")

        # Check if barcode is valid with regex
        if not re.match(r'^(\d\d|AG|CF)\d\d\d\d\d\d(\d\d)?$', code.upper()):
            log_csv(usr_obj, code, scan_mode, False)
            return fail_func(f"'{code}' is not a valid format")

        url = f"https://johndeere.service-now.com/alm_asset_list.do?sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_query=GOTO123TEXTQUERY321%3d{code}&sysparm_query_encoded=GOTO123TEXTQUERY321%3d12345&sysparm_view="

        driver.get(url)

        # After barcode is scanned, move to URL, switch to iframe, and grab site attributes
        try:
            alert = driver.switch_to.alert
            alert.accept()
            print("alert accepted")
        except:
            print("no alert")

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('gsft_main'))

[DEBUG  ] [http          ]//localhost:9515 "POST /session/10c51be2819e01a97a7d306b88fe4cfb/url HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[DEBUG  ] [Remote response] status=200 | data={"value":null} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '14', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
[DEBUG  ] Finished Request
[DEBUG  ] GET http://localhost:9515/session/10c51be2819e01a97a7d306b88fe4cfb/alert/text {}
no alert


When I go to the provide URL, I see no alert... only a login page. I'm assuming it's because you are already logged in and we aren't. Are you sure there's a JS alert? Have you tried waiting for the alert to appear? Right click on the alert and see if you have the option to inspect.

Right.  Remember that Selenium acts in real time.  There's no guarantee that the page has been rendered or even fully loaded when driver.get returns.  You need to wait for the iframe to exist before you can switch to it.  And yes, siwtch_to.alert is a property and does not require parens.
